# Average of top 10 values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

My data set looks like this:

```
Time    Date        ID        Value
12 am   1st Oct     1001      100
12 am   2nd Oct     1001      203
12 am   3rd Oct     1001      403
....    ......      ....      ....
11 pm   20th Oct    1001      566
12 am   1st Oct     1002      150
12 am   2nd Oct     1002      153
12 am   3rd Oct     1002      403
....    ......      ....      ....
11 pm   10th Oct    1002      666
```

For each customer, I have 20 days of data for each hour.  I need to calculate and show the average of top 10 values for each hour out of that 20 days for each customer.

The output will look like this...

```
Time  ID     Average
12am  1001   105
1am   1001   056
...   ....   ...
11pm  1001   298
12am  1002   456
1am   1002   856
...    ...   ...
11pm  1002   166
```

How can I do that using Power BI?

Comment: *"[It is actually now considered a violation of community rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on/417578#417578)"* (begging for accepts). *"Do not use the comment sections to encourage or otherwise nudge users towards accepting answers or voting, as the site functionality covers this today."*

Comment: TAB characters may not render as expected here. An alternative is to use [Markdown tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).